# Is there a index file for python releases like nodejs does?

Tags: python

Node.js has an index file to easily get all releases with additional info. Is there a file like this for python too? I've searched the python FTP directory but couldn't find a file like this.

node's index file: https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've researched there is none, so I created this express app to scrape the FTP page and get the versions as an array. It's live on Heroku but at the time you are seeing this post it may have gotten down. You can spin up your own server from this repo.

PS: I didn't spend much time on it, it just does the job.

[GitHub](https://github.com/batuhanyndny/python_release_index)

[Heroku](https://agile-hamlet-42000.herokuapp.com/)